# React JS Adding Remove button to each item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I currently have a button at the bottom of the page which removes the item at the second index (position 1) when pressed i.e. James Johnson then George Brown.

However I want to add this button to every item in the list so it removes the item at that index.

Example,

John Smith - Remove

James Johnson - Remove

George Brown - Remove

Clicking the Remove button next to the name would remove that item.

**friendsActions.js**

```
import * as f from '../constants'

export const addFriend = ({ firstname, lastname }) => ({
  type: f.ADD_FRIEND,
  frienditem: {
    firstname,
    lastname,
  },  
})

export const removeFriend = ({ key }) => ({
   type: f.REMOVE_FRIEND,
  key,
})
```

**friendsReducer.js**

```
import * as f from '../constants'

const initialState = [
  { firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Smith' },
  { firstname: 'James', lastname: 'Johnson' },
  { firstname: 'George', lastname: 'Brown' },
 ]

const friendsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case f.ADD_FRIEND:
      return [...state, action.frienditem] 
    case f.REMOVE_FRIEND:
      console.log('removing friend with key ' + action.key)
      return [...state.slice(0, action.key), ...state.slice(action.key + 1)]
    default:
       return state
  }
 }

export default friendsReducer
```

**index.js (constants)**

```
export const ADD_FRIEND = 'ADD_FRIEND'
export const REMOVE_FRIEND = 'REMOVE_FRIEND'
friendsContainer.js

import React from 'react'
import Page from '../components/Page'

import FriendList from '../containers/FriendList'

import { css } from 'glamor'

const FriendContainer = props => (
  <Page title="Friends List" colour="blue">
    <FriendList {...props} />
  </Page>
)

export default FriendContainer
```

**friendsList.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { css } from 'glamor'

const Friend = ({ firstname, lastname }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        {firstname} {lastname}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
)

const FriendList = ({ friends, addFriend, removeFriend }) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      {friends.map((frn, i) => (
        <Friend key={++i} firstname={frn.firstname} lastname={frn.lastname} />
      ))}
    </div>
    <button onClick={() => addFriend({ firstname: 'New', lastname: 'Friend' })}>
      Add Friend
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => removeFriend({ key: 1 })}>Remove Friend</button>
  </div>
)

export default FriendList
```

Comment: does removing a fiend work is you specify a different key value?

Comment: yeah only for 0, 1 or 2 though as there are only 3 records initially. so if key is replaced by the array index it should work but unsure how to do this and get the function to work outside of FriendList

Comment: You should give your person objects an id and use that as the key rather than the map index when you're iterating over the array.

Comment: @H1ggsy all you do is take the map index which is i and use it as the key value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In friendList.js

```
const FriendList = ({ friends, addFriend, removeFriend }) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      {friends.map((frn, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
           <Friend firstname={frn.firstname} lastname={frn.lastname} />
           /* with some styling */
           <button onClick={() => removeFriend({ key: i })}>Remove Friend</button>
        </div> 
      ))}
    </div>
    <button onClick={() => addFriend({ firstname: 'New', lastname: 'Friend' })}>
      Add Friend
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: this gives an error "[js] JSX expressions must have one parent element" ?

Comment: my mistake. you should wrap Freind component and button with div or something. And move key props to parent component. And you should remove ++ in key props too. I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you, this now works, yeah i noticed the ++ needed to be removed.

Comment: You're welcome :D. It would be better add key props in friend list array.